# What does “Register for COM Interop” actually do? Q2

Tags: com-interop, regasm

What exactly does the VS project option "Register for COM interop" actually do? 
Because when I build my library with this option enabled I'm able to view it in the COM tab inside the VS Add Reference screen.
But if I build without this and then run regasm manually (**already including /codebase parameter**) I can't see it in the COM Dll list, neither inside VS Add Reference screen or VB6 References screen. So, I'm wondering -- what does VS2010 do that I'm not doing?

I already searched for this topic inside StackOverflow, and found this link, which didn't solve my problem:
[What does "Register for COM Interop" actually do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534600/what-does-register-for-com-interop-actually-do)

Regasm shows me: Types registered successfully
So, I don't have any extra info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio enumerate the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\TypeLib registry key to fill the COM tab.  Drop Wow6432Node if you use the 32-bit version of Windows.

So what's missing is that you forgot to ask Regasm.exe to register the type library.  You need to also use the /tlb option.

Comment: Thanks, I used regasm with "/tlb:" parameter. Now it's working fine