# Error 429 activex component can't create object while using self create reference

Tags: c#, excel, vba, dll, activex

I created some add-in for excel in C#. In it is one public class for using in VBA. On my machine all works ok. When I install add-in on tester computer (I'm using InstallShield 2015 Limited Edition for Visual Studio to create setup file) I can't set object.

C# code

```cs
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace PMTAddin
{
    [Guid("B2350EC1-522E-4B75-BB02-86BB0FD1A60E")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class PublicClass
    {
        public void test()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                        "test."
                    , "test"
                    , System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK
                    , System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error
                );
        }

        private int GetWorksheetID(Excel.Workbook wb, string worksheetName)
        {
            int result = 0;


            foreach (Excel.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
            {
                if (ws.Name == worksheetName)
                {
                    result = ws.Index;
                    break;
                }

            }

            return result;
        }

        [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
        {
            Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"));
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "InprocServer32"), true);
            key.SetValue("", System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\mscoree.dll", RegistryValueKind.String);
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
        public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
        {
            Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type, "Programmable"), false);
        }

        private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type, string subKeyName)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            s.Append(@"CLSID\{");
            s.Append(type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper());
            s.Append(@"}\");
            s.Append(subKeyName);
            return s.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

In VBA project I checked reference to it on the list. It calls PMT.

VBA

```vb
Sub dsf()
    Dim o As PMT.PublicClass
    Set o = New PMT.PublicClass 'at this lane on other computer I got error 429. On my computer all work smoothly and method test is running.

    o.test
End Sub
```

I thought that maybe it was something .NET Framework, but it is installed. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I create two diffrent version for bittnes, but the same error.

But I found some new info. In registry on my computer it looks like this
[image: Registry on dev machine]

and on tester machine it looks like this
[image: Registry on test machine]

There are no CodeBase value... Do you think this is the problem? If it is, how I need to modify RegisterFunction method to correct this?

Comment: Use regasm.exe on the failing machine to manually register the DLL, if that makes it work your installer is not registering the DLL correctly.

Comment: I registered it manually. I got _Types registered successfully
Assembly exported to 'PATH', and the type library was registered successfully_, but the problem is still there.

Comment: The bitness of the DLL & Office match?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. How to check bitness of DLL?

Comment: If your using 64 bit Excel the DLL must be (compiled as) 64 bit, ditto for 32 bit.

Comment: @AlexK. New info above

Comment: The Codebase value is very important.  If it is missing then the assembly must to stored in the GAC.

Comment: Can give mem more information, what I should to do?

Comment: Is this really an "addin" (there is a specific VS project type) or is it a 'Class Library' (otherwise known as Assemblt/DLL)?

Comment: Check out this Q&A to see RegAsm.exe explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534600/what-does-register-for-com-interop-actually-do

Comment: @SMeaden Yes, it is really an addin (specyfic project in VS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long seeking I found the solution. It's kind of partial, because for 64 bit Excel we need to register library manually (maybe someone knows, how to add bat file to installation file).

I found the answer on this [site](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2015/02/25/registering-a-com-add-in-with-installsheild-le/).

While creating Install Shield instalation file we need to do two things.

1. Add .tlb file to application files (this step was done by me, before posting on stackoverflow)
2. Click right on project.Primary output file and choose properities like in screenshot (for *.tlb file we need to check the same, but without "COM Interop")
   [image]

**Without this the installer will not properlly register add-in in registry.**

Install file created like this would register add-in for **32-bit excel only**. If you want to use it also in 64-bit Excel you need to register library manually. I created simple bat file like this:

```
c:
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
regasm.exe "[pathToDLL]\AddInName.dll" /tlb:"[pathToDLL]\AddInName.tlb" /codebase 
pause
```

Remember, that you need to run it with admin rights.