# IKVM.NET & Excel VBA

Tags: java, .net, excel, vba, ikvm

I'm using `IKVM.NET` in order to convert a `Java` library (signally, [Strata](https://github.com/OpenGamma/Strata)) into a `.NET` library. Here are the steps I perform:

1. I download [the latest Strata release](https://github.com/OpenGamma/Strata/releases/download/v2.2.0/strata-dist-2.2.0.zip).
2. I unzip all the `JAR` files contained into the `lib` folder of the archive to `C:\Strata\`, including the following auxiliary libraries:

   - *commons-math3-3.6.1.jar*
   - *guava-26.0-jre.jar*
   - *joda-beans-2.4.0.jar*
   - *joda-convert-2.2.0.jar*
   - *slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar*
3. I generate a keyfile for the library I want to create using the command `sn -k "C:\Strata\Strata.snk"`.
4. Using the binary bytecode compiler of `IKVM.NET`, I convert the `JAR` files of `Strata` into a `.NET` library with the following command: `ikvmc -out:"C:\Strata\Strata.dll" -keyfile:"C:\Strata\Strata.snk" -assembly:Strata -version:2.2.0 -fileversion:2.2.0 -target:library -platform:anycpu -recurse:"C:\Strata\*.jar"`.

Once the process described above is done, even if a few warnings concerning missing classes are shown, I obtain a working `.NET` wrapper of `Strata`. If I create a new `Visual Studio` project referencing the `Strata.dll` assembly, I'm capable of using its classes and methods without problems.

What I would really love to achieve is to make the wrapper work in `Excel VBA` macros, so that I can instantiate and use `Strata` classes in the subs, according to the contents of the sheets.

This is what I tried so far, but to no avail:

1. I register all the `IKVM.NET` libraries and the `Strata` wrapper into the `GAC` as follows: `gacutil /i "C:\IKVM\IKVM.*.dll"`, `gacutil /i "C:\Strata\Strata.dll"`.
2. I register the `Strata` wrapper as `COM` component and I create its types library as follows: `regasm /codebase /tlb "C:\Strata\Strata.dll"`.

Now, when I open `Excel` and I go under `Development > Visual Basic > Tools > References...` I can see the `TLB` file of `Strata` (located at "C:\Strata\Strata.tlb") and I can add it to the current project. But as soon as I type something the window or I open the `Objects Browser`, `Excel` crashes without providing any meaningful information about what's going on.

I'm totally clueless about this issue.

Is my registration process correct? Do I have to register the `IKVM.NET` libraries too and create their type libraries? Should I include them into the `Excel VBA` project together with the `Strata` wrapper type libraries? Could the problem be caused by the fact that I'm using a x64 version of `Excel` and the wrapper has been compiled under `AnyCPU`? Do I need to edit the wrapper by adding a `ComVisible` attribute on every public class? May this problem be due to the fact that the wrapper contains weird method names like “\_Build01_\p”?

Comment: I've always added a ComVisible attribute for each public class, seems to work ok. Registration looks fine, but you can use the Register for COM interop option too (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534600/what-does-register-for-com-interop-actually-do). Try targeting x86 explicitly. I'm assuming you are using the unmanaged exports library, you added `[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` attribute to the class? Might be helpful to see the code you are making into the dll.

Comment: Dear Ryan, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot use the "Register for COM Interop" option because I'm just producing a .NET library from JAR files without relying on a Visual Studio project and ad-hoc code. And this is the exact same reason I should programmatically edit the output library in order to add the ComVisible attributes, if needed. All I do is to create a .NET library from the JARs, using ikvmc, as described in the first part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use IKVM.NET you can use Java directly to build an Excel add-in.

To build an Excel add-in in Java instead of having to use .NET, see https://exceljava.com.

There is even a Strata-Excel project that you might be interested in that wraps the Strata library in an Excel add-in: https://github.com/exceljava/strata-excel

I think you should find this much more convenient than converting the Java libraries to .NET.